# getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to update my UI by getting the current fragment in my container and calling its method. My layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <!-- The main content view -->
     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/frmContentFrame"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:clickable="true" />
     <!-- The navigation drawer -->
     <ListView android:id="@+id/lstLeftDrawer"
         android:layout_width="240dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
         android:background="@color/SlideMenuBlue"
         android:divider="@color/White"
         android:dividerHeight="1dp"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_padding"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_padding"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am transitioning between Fragments(android.support.v4.app) like so

```
//Switches views
public void switchContent(final Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.frmContentFrame, fragment, "CURRENT_FRAGMENT")
    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

And when I call my update UI method my fragment is null. Here is the code

```
public void updateUI() {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("CURRENT_FRAGMENT");
    System.out.println(fragment);

    if((FragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("CURRENT_FRAGMENT") != null){
        FragmentA frag = (FragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("CURRENT_FRAGMENT");
        frag.updateUIStatusA();
    }
    else if((FragmentB) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("CURRENT_FRAGMENT") != null){
        FragmentB frag = (FragmentB) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("CURRENT_FRAGMENT");
        frag.updateUIStatusB();
    }
}
```

The weird thing is, while the fragment is returning null I get a `ClassCastException` like the following

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.activity.fragments.FragmentB cannot be cast to com.example.activity.fragments.FragmentA
```

Why is it that it knows in the error what fragment I have in my container but returns null when I try to retrieve it?

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: you get the CCE because the fragment at CURRENT_FRAGMENT could be an A or B. you need to get the fragment, then check if it's a particular `instanceof` something before you cast.

Comment: for the null, remember that fragment transactions are asynchronous. so after you call `commit()`, you aren't guaranteed that a subsequent find fragment will return the fragment.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman thank you for your input. I changed to this and it worked great. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to use unique tags and don't forget to add your tag in the `backstack`. Example:

```
//Switches views
public void switchContent(final Fragment fragment) {
   getSupportFragmentManager()
   .beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.frmContentFrame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
   .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
   .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
   .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Then your update method could look like this

```
public void updateUI() {
Fragment fragmentA = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentA.class.getSimpleName());
Fragment fragmentB = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentB.class.getSimpleName());

if (fragmentA != null)
  fragmentA.updateUIstatusA();

if (fragmentB != null)
  fragmentB.updateUIstatusB();

}
```